# Measure flutter application startup time

Tags: flutter

I am looking for some way to measure startup time of an application. From a moment of clicking the app icon till the moment, when for example login page is visible to the user.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, IntelliJ I think you can Flutter Performance, Dart Dev Tools.

Comment: When  I use Flutter Performance and quit Flutter app, connection with debugger is lost.

Answer (score 16):

Run

```
flutter run --trace-startup --profile
```

The trace output is saved as a JSON file called `start_up_info.json` under the `build` directory of your Flutter project. The output lists the elapsed time from app startup to these trace events (captured in microseconds):

- Time to enter the Flutter engine code.
- Time to render the first frame of the app.
- Time to initialize the Flutter framework.
- Time to complete the Flutter framework initialization.

For example:

```
content_copy
{
  "engineEnterTimestampMicros": 96025565262,
  "timeToFirstFrameMicros": 2171978,
  "timeToFrameworkInitMicros": 514585,
  "timeAfterFrameworkInitMicros": 1657393
}
```

[Source](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#measuring-app-startup-time)

Comment: how to interpret these timings,
Is this interpretation correct?

1) engineEnterTimestampMicros -  is a point in time
i.e. the point in time at which flutter engine begins executing
2) timeToFirstFrameMicros -  time taken for first frame from point 1.
3) timeToFrameworkInitMicros - time taken for framework to get initialised measured from point 1.
4) timeAfterFrameworkInitMicros - time taken for rendering UI after framework is ready measured from point 1.

Comment: The app sits around with the splash screen icon on the screen for much longer than `timeToFirstFrameMicros`. I'm assuming "first frame" here is the first frame of the splash screen? How do you measure the amount of time the app spends running user code before an actual frame is drawn?