# How to do CPU profiling / Performance profiling for startup phase of Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, profiling

My flutter application is a bit slow when booting, so I need to know what is happening during the startup. More specifically, I want to use the Performance and CPU Profiler tabs of Flutter DevTools.

However, to use those DevTools, I need to open the DevTools page, click "record", and then click "start recording" / "refresh". However, I am not quick enough (and IMHO it is also not a good idea) to quickly do these steps when the app is starting up, in order to capture information about startup.

Thus I wonder what I should do? Thanks!

P.S. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879839/measure-flutter-application-startup-time) does not work, because that does not talk about CPU profiling. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115311/flutter-how-to-force-an-application-restart-in-production-mode) also does not work, because it is not a "real" restart and many states are not re-inited, etc.

P.S. A sample screenshot of Performance and CPU Profiler tab:

[image]

[image]