# How to improve app startup profiling for flutter?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, profiling, devtools

I am facing a delay in my flutter app at startup for android, the delay is before execution of dart code begins.
Mostly it is due to Geolocator plugin.
I have raised a ticket with them, however I want to find out how much time SDKs are taking on startup using profiling. Dev tools time line tab is not showing anything even when i checked all options.
Is there any better way to do this, using third party tools, or native side profiling (android).

Comment: did u read this: https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/ui-performance

Comment: Yes I have gone through it

Answer (score 0):

This answer on stack overflow shows how to profile app startup

Run:

> flutter run --trace-startup --profile

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61830649/1636247